# Cropping many textfiles at once

Tags: r, text

I have a folder on my PC with 21765 different textfiles containing data from 21765 weather stations in Europe. They contain mean temperatures for every single day from 1860-2021. In my analysis I only need 2000-2021

All these stations report data in a similar fashion.

Is there a way for me in R or otherwise to cut away all the data before 2000 from all 21765 files?

Some stations only have data from 2010-2020. I would like to remove these textfiles as well

Picture:
[image]

Comment: Can you paste one of the file in the question so that we can copy and create our own similar text file? We can't do that with an image.

Comment: You certainly could. Among other options, you could (1) read the text files with readLines and use a regular expression to remove all lines with dates not in your range, (2) parse the tables into dataframes and exclude all dates not in your range. If you offer us a reproducible example it would help us help ypu.